# FormControlName not displayed on view mode

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control, formgroups

I'm using a rective form to display some information of my form. The fact is that all fields of the formgroup render the value except one. i need to refresh page before getting value.
Here is a reduced version of my code

.ts file

```
        private getPhaseParId(id: number) {
            this.phasesService.getPhaseParId(id)
              .subscribe(
                (phase: Phase) => {
                  if (phase) {
                    this.maPhase = phase;
    console.log("before updatePhaseFormulaire()",this.phaseFormulaire.get('predecesseur').value);
                    this.updatePhaseFormulaire();                
   console.log("after updatePhaseFormulaire()",this.phaseFormulaire.get('predecesseur').value);
                    
                  } else {
                    // else bloc treatment
                  }
                },
                erreur => {
                  // error bloc treatment
                })
          }
    
        private updatePhaseFormulaire(): void {   
            this.phaseFormulaire.patchValue({
              id: this.maPhase.id,
              nom: this.maPhase.nom,
              predecesseur: this.maPhase?.predecesseur      
            })    
          }
```

and .html snippet

```
<form [formGroup]="phaseFormulaire" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <select class="form-input heightFixed" id="predecesseur"
        formControlName="predecesseur"
        title="{{ 'phase.formulaire.predecesseur.input.infobulle' | translate}}">
        <option [ngValue]="null||undefined" *ngIf="phaseListe && phaseListe.length > 0">
          {{ 'phase.formulaire.predecesseur.placeholder.libelle' | translate}}
        </option>
        <option [ngValue]="null||undefined" *ngIf="!phaseListe || phaseListe.length === 0">
          {{ 'phase.formulaire.predecesseur.aucunPredecesseur.libelle' | translate}}
        </option>
        <option [ngValue]="predecesseur" *ngFor="let predecesseur of predecesseursListe | orderBy:'nom'" [attr.selected]="predecesseur.id == this.maPhase?.predecesseur?.id ? true : null">
          {{predecesseur.nom}}
        </option>
      </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

As I explain as explained above, predecesseur formControlName does not display anything on the page
(refer to the image)[image]

but with console.log befor and after, i have this output:

- before updatePhaseFormulaire: `Phase {}`
- after updatePhaseFormulaire: `{id: 1, nom: 'Admissibilité',statutOk: 'Accepté', statutKo: 'Refusé', …}`

I've tried to add  `ngAfterViewInit()` but not fix it. Does anyone has idea to fix this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to double-check if the FormControlName attribute is correctly set on the  element in your HTML template. Ensure that it matches the name of the control in your form.

Answer (score 0):

See that your's select options has to value "objects" (yu're equal to "predecesseur"), not a single string or number. I imagine you want to do some like (see that ngValue is predecesseur.id

```
<option [ngValue]="predecesseur.id" 
         *ngFor="let predecesseur of predecesseursListe | orderBy:'nom'" ...>
          {{predecesseur.nom}}
</option>
```

**Update** if we really want to asign a complex object we have two options, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)

1. Equal the formControl to the same object, some like

   ```
   this.phaseFormulaire.patchValue({
                 id: this.maPhase.id,
                 nom: this.maPhase.nom,
                 predecesseur:this.predecesseursListe.find(x=>x.id==this.maPhase?.predecesseur)
               })
   ```
2. Use a compare function

   ```
   <select [compareWith]="compareFn"  
        [formControl]="selectedCountriesControl">
      ...
   </select>

   compareFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
       return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
   }
   ```

Comment: using predecesseur.id did not fix the issue. Instead of [ngValue], I use [attr.value] and it work fine. I don't know why because [ngValue] is supposed to  bind complex objects and predecessoeur is one. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @dakim236, I update my response, try it and avoid use [attr.value]

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by changing the attribute `[ngValue]` in the `<option>` tag to: `[attr.value]`